# Find out all places where a user ID (from the user info list) is used on a site?

Tags: lookup-column, user-accounts, user-information-list

Given that user fields are lookups to the user information list in a particular site, is there an easy way to find all user fields in the site that are populated with a particular user ID?

We recently switched from Windows/classic auth to claims, and now the user information list has a bunch of duplicate entries for users, some with their AD formatted login, like

```
i:0#.w|domain\username
```

and some with their claims formatted login, like

```
i:0e.t|some-type-of-code|username@domain.company.com
```

I want to de-dupe the list, but I don't want to arbitrarily remove all the `domain\user` style entries because I'm worried that some of those list items might be the lookup IDs in some fields somewhere on the site. If I can find those, I can swap them out for the IDs of the user's claims formatted entry.

So given a specific user ID from the user information list, is there an easy way to find out everywhere it's used on the site?

Comment: Hi. You convert to claims WebApplication after that? https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/sharepoint-server/convert-spwebapplication?view=sharepoint-server-ps

Comment: I don't know, I'm not the SP Admin and I didn't do the conversion to claims.  All I know is, we're using claims now (and it works just fine), but there are duplicate entries in the user info list. I may end up deleting this question anyway because we actually solved the issue that I _thought_ was caused by the duplicate entries.

Answer (score 0):

This situation is most likely due to the fact that you did not convert web applications to claims.  This often happens after a migration or change to an organization's authentication scheme.
First of all, you need to make this conversion - https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/sharepoint-server/convert-spwebapplication?view=sharepoint-server-ps
After that, users who have become duplicates must be migrated to existing - https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/sharepoint-server/move-spuser?view=sharepoint-server-ps
Be careful as this method does not update rights and permissions, it only updates lookup values ​​and fields related to creation and modification.